# Windows Compact 7: Modify existing control panel application

Tags: windows-ce, control-panel, windows-embedded-compact

I am replacing a backlight driver for a device running Windows Embedded Compact 7.  I'm hoping I can find the source for the application and modify it to call my driver instead of the old one.

Is there a way to tie my driver's functionality into the existing "Display" Control Panel application?  Is the source available for these applications and where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up through CE 6.0, the source code for all Windows CE Control Panels can be found on the development PC where Platform Builder is installed at:

`%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\WCESHELLFE\OAK\CTLPNL`

I don't have a CE 7.0 installation handy to verify the location, but I suspect it's going to be in the same place or something very similar if you're using a standard shell (`SYSGEN_CTLPNL`).  If you're using the new "Silverlight" shell ('SYSGEN_CTLPNL2`), then it's likely to be in a different location, but all of the source is still available.

Comment: This is still where the control panel applications live in CE 7.0.

The meat of the applications can be found more specifically at:
`%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\WCESHELLFE\OAK\CTLPNL\CPLMAIN`